# ATG baseline_update.sh failing with error: No data records output

Tags: java, atg, endeca

I was able to install ATG, endeca and was able to get it up and running but after formatting my machine I reinstalled everything but on running baseline-update.sh getting below error:

```
2018-12-31 22:58:02,890 ERROR [cas] [cas-TCCen-last-mile-crawl-worker-1] com.endeca.itl.executor.TaskManager.[TCCen-last-mile-crawl]: Fatal execution error performing work "MdexOutputSink-1677370194 notified input closed (AsynchronousChannel-263848415)". Aborting crawl.
com.endeca.itl.executor.FatalExecutionException: No data records output: There are no New or Updated records
    at com.endeca.itl.executor.output.mdex.MdexOutputSink.processDataInputClosed(MdexOutputSink.java:238)
    at com.endeca.itl.executor.output.mdex.MdexOutputSink.notifyInputClosed(MdexOutputSink.java:204)
    at com.endeca.itl.executor.TaskManager$4.work(TaskManager.java:353)
    at com.endeca.itl.executor.WorkExecutor$WorkRunnable.run(WorkExecutor.java:194)f
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.endeca.itl.util.LoggingContextAwareThread.run(LoggingContextAwareThread.java:71)
```

FYI: Using ATG 11.2 (platform, reference store, CAS, MDEX, Tools and framework, Platform services, oracle DB 12c)

index-config.json file contents

```
{
  "indexConfig" : {
      "attributes" : {
        "jcr:primaryType" : "endeca:unstructured",
        "record.id" : {
          "propertyDataType" : "ALPHA",
          "jcr:primaryType" : "endeca:property",
          "isRecordFilterable" : true
        },
    "product.price_range" : {
          "displayOrder" : 1,
          "mergeAction" : "UPDATE",
          "jcr:primaryType" : "endeca:dimension",
          "rangeComparisonType" : "FLOAT"
        }
      },
      "precedenceRules" : {
      },
      "searchIndexConfig" : {
        "isWildcardEnabledInDimensionSearch" : true,
        "spellingDictMaxWordLength" : 16,
        "spellingDictMinNumWordOccurrences" : 4,
        "spellingDictMinWordLength" : 3
      }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I did restarted all the services, restarted machine but no luck same output. Not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: Looks like you are running baseline_update.sh from Endeca side.  If that's the case, your CAS system may not have any records pushed from ATG end.  To get records from ATG, you have to open ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin component in ACC and trigger the baseline indexing from there.

Comment: I already did that but getting same error. I even tried to do the full-deployment from BCC but same output.

Comment: Try running CatalogMaintenanceService first and then trigger indexing from ATG.  (Suggest to put what you already tried so far in the post for better clarity and to avoid redundancy)

Comment: Also check what VariantProducer components are engaged, for instance, if you have used LocaleVariantProducer, ensure that you had set the desired language (say "en") in your ATG configuration (like SiteRepository, etc).  Please enable loggingDebug for all such components and observe the logs for apparent issues.

Comment: What is the output from the `/atg/commerce/endeca/index/ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin/` in dyn/admin ?